# Eclipse: is there a way to specify the code formatting style using the style of the current source file?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

I know I can go through and manually set all of the various options for the Eclipse Java formatter, and then easily apply that style to any Java file.

Is there a way to go the other direction?  Given a Java file, output the Eclipse formatter settings that match (to some degree of closeness) the formatting of that file?  I'd like to be able to edit existing code and use a matching style, rather than impose a new style.  And I'd prefer not to have to do this multiple times for different code styles.

The point here isn't to have something learn the coding conventions for my organization; for code written in-house I just did it by hand since there's only one set of conventions.  What's hard is that there are many projects from outside organizations mixed in that use different coding conventions, and I'd like to adjust my settings to match those existing projects.  They're not going to take mine :-).

Preferably for Eclipse 3.7, but I'll switch to 4.x if that's what it takes.

Comment: Unlikely.  You're asking for a tool that learns the style correctly.   It is already almost impossible to make people happy with code layout; witness you for example.  If the tool learns anything wrong, you'll reject it. So there's little motivation for somebody to even to try to build such a tool.

Comment: @IraBaxter, I'm not looking to be happy - I'd settle for not-miserable.  I think you're being too gloomy here about the possibility of a tool; the world is filled with tools that make code formatting a slightly better experience.  They don't have to be perfect.

Comment: I supply some of those tools.  You'd be astonished at how often they get rejected because they don't do some arcane layout thing.   My personal opinion is that *any* reasonable standard layout in an organization is much better than everybody doing as they please.   Asking the tool to "learn the style" is sure fire way to meet failure (and is "rejected because it won't *learn* my style, let alone do it").   If you simply don't want to be miserable, why doesn't Astyle meet your needs?   No, it doesn't learn your style but it has a lot of options and some of them ought to be decent.

Comment: Got it - I clarified my question.  It's not about my one style, it's about the styles for the 15 other projects I have to work on, all of which use their own, different style.  If I get to decide the coding conventions, I'll happily take $ANY_STYLE_THAT_A_TOOL_CAN_AUTOMATE.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, for java projects, the code-formatter settings are specific to the workspace, not to the project. the settings are at Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter.

so if someone gives your a isolated source-file or eclipse project, that entity will not contain any eclipse workspace-specific code-formatter settings.

if you have access to the original workspace from where that source/project was obtained, you can export the settings from there (Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter->Export All).

Comment: FYI, there's an option under Java > Code Style > Formatter that lets you change the style per project, not per workspace.  But I think you missed the point of the question: if you don't have formatter settings, and you do have a Java file, is there a tool to figure out the settings that match the file?

Comment: @JamesMoore: I guess my point is, why don't you just set the style once and live with it?

Comment: Imagine you have multiple different projects that you work on, each with a different style.  They're not your styles, you have to work with the existing style.  It's really time-consuming to go through and figure out the settings for each one.

Comment: i am assuming you got these projects from someone and they didn't appear out of thin air. why don't you ask that person to export his IDE settings, so you can import the same. once you have these settings (xml files) you can even save them in your code repo so others can use it.
this is a cold start problem. once you get the settings, problem solved. until then, you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and short answer: **no**. There is no support for that in Eclipse and no plugin that will do that for you in EclipseCentral.

Sorry :(